# Use data (Json), create new element, row and columns for each object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm new at JavaScript.
We are supposed to get data from here: https://stryk.herokuapp.com/tipset
then use the data, creating a new row (`tr`) with columns (`td`) for each game (I can't change anything in the HTML file). It supposes to look something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ejGx.png

I can't figure out how to loop through the data and then use it.

```
import {getData} from './getdata.js';
let data = getData();
event();

function createTR(text) {
    var x = document.createElement("TR");
    x.setAttribute("class", "myTr");
    document.getElementById("table").appendChild(x);
  
    var y = document.createElement("TD");
    var t = document.createTextNode(text);
    y.appendChild(t);
    document.querySelector(".myTr").appendChild(y);
}


function event() {
    document.querySelector('#active').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
    data.then(createTR);
}
```

```
export function getData() {
    return fetch('https://stryk.herokuapp.com/tipset')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        
        .then(function (data) {
            console.dir(data);
            
                
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in understanding that your question is: I have some JSON data with multiple elements. How do I traverse those elements in javascript?  If that is correct, you need three steps.

First convert the JSON to an object

```
   var dataobj = JSON_parse(data)
```

then you can get an array of the keys in the object

```
   var datakeys = Object.keys(dataobj)
```

then you traverse the obj using a for loop

```
   for (var i = 0; i < datakeys.length; i++) {
      var dataval = dataobj[datakeys[i]] 
      // make your new row with the data
   }
```